# How to set caption text wider than the image

Tags: lightbox2

In Lightbox2 I'm trying to get the caption text centred and wider than the image. I'm using the CSS file section at:

```
.lb-data .lb-details {
width: 100%;
float: left;
text-align: center;
line-height: 1.2em;
}
```

By increasing "width" I can get wider text to the right and by changing the "float" to right I can get the wider text to hang to the left.

I've also tried setting "float" to "none" and "inherit" with no success.

What I want to do is have a portrait image with centred text wider than the image.

As the text can be made to be wider than the image I don't think it's a container issue but I could be wrong.

Any suggestions? All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is a container issue. The `div.lb-dataContainer` get's a width applied to it that matches the image container above it. To make it wider, you can override it by either by editing the `lightbox.js` source or by using CSS, ex. `.lb-dataContainer { width: 100% !important; }`

[image]